# Counting printed pages in OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, printing, macos-carbon

I'm developing an app for the Mac OS X that provides various system statistics. I have a little problem with the printer because I have never worked with it before. Is there any way to listen to the printer and count pages printed in color and in b&w?

Edit: I remember that I was using a Mac OS X kiosk machine once and it offered color and b&w prints priced per page, so there must be a way to do this. Also, I develop this app for my own needs and for practice so the solution doesn't have to be universal.

Comment: Keep in mind that printers are often shared in a network and that the page count might just not be determinable from a client machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure access to this information is specific to individual printer models. I don't believe there's a system API that will help you here as it would require querying individual printer drivers or utilities.

The [Core Printing Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/Reference/reference.html) which is the documentation for the Mac OS X printing API doesn't appear to contain any calls that would allow you to extract this information from a printer.